# Converting a type Object to a type JButton?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

Hi guys I have a problem, I have an object of type Object Class and I want to convert it to an object of type java.swing.JButton is there any ways to do that? 
here is the code:

```
private void EventSelectedFromList(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        // add code here
        try
        {
            String eventName = (String)EventList.getSelectedItem();// get the event 
            EventSetDescriptor ed = eventValue(events,eventName);
            if(ed.getListenerType() == ActionListener.class){// check if selected event has an actionListerner listener
                AddEventHandlerButton.setEnabled(true);// Enable eventhandler button
                String objectName = (String) ObjectList.getSelectedItem();
                Object ob = FindObject(hm, objectName);// retrieve the object from hashmap
                // now 'ob' of type of JButton, I want to add ActionListener to this JButton???

                Class zzz = ob.getClass();
                System.out.println(zzz);

            } else {
                AddEventHandlerButton.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }catch(Exception ex){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                "Error",
                "Inane error",
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }

    }
```

any ideas?
thanks

Comment: what does FindObject() method do ? rather what objects are stored in hashmap ?

Comment: FindObject() checks the selected object name from combobox against its object type in the hashmap

Comment: does it return you JButton or component type ?

Answer (score 5):

You *probably* just want a cast (possibly with an `instanceof` check first, as shown by Andreas; it depends on what you want to happen if the object you find isn't a `JButton`):

```
JButton button = (JButton) ob;
```

but there's more detail to go into here. You should differentiate between the type of an *object* and the type of a *variable*.

In your case, the type of `ob` itself is definitely `Object`. However, the value of `ob` may be a reference to an instance of `JButton` - in which case you're okay to cast, as above.

Note that this doesn't change the type of the *object* at all. Once an object has been created, it will never change its type. All you're doing is declaring a new variable of type `JButton` and asking the JVM to check that the value of `ob` really *does* refer to an instance of `JButton` (or a subclass; or that it's a null reference). If that's the case, the value of `button` will end up being the same as the value of `ob` (i.e. a reference to the same object). If it's not, a `ClassCastException` will be thrown.

Do you see what I mean about the difference between the type of the variable and the type of the object it happens to refer to? It's very important to understand this difference.

Comment: I think that he already knows how to cast, as he used cast before in his code. The question was about casting zzz into a JButton. (but I might be wrong)

Comment: @Colin: I don't think so, given the comment: `// now 'ob' of type of JButton, I want to add ActionListener to this JButton???`

Comment: hum, you're right. But it's really strange to ask how to cast when you have done a cast two line above.

Answer (score 2):

Converting a Class instance to a JButton instance, aka casting, is not possible, not the right way. But you use the Class object to create a *new* instance of JButton:

```
 Class<JButton> buttonClass = JButton.class;
 JButton button = buttonClass.newInstance();
```

But it looks like you expect to get a button through findObject and want to add a listener to an already existing button, I suggest doing it like that:

```
Object ob = findObject(hm, objectName);
if (!(ob instanceof JButton)) {
   // handle error and return/throw exception
}
JButton button = (JButton) ob;
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){ 
   // implement methods
});
```

Comment: He's not trying to convert the instance of `Class<T>` - he's already *got* a reference to a `JButton`, just in a variable of type `Object`. I believe the `Class` part of the code is just to demonstrate the type of the object that `ob` refers to.

Comment: I was mislead by the wording "Object Class" and the presence of that "zzz" variable... native speakers have a slight advantage in decoding questions ;-)